# Is it possible to import string, split it to words, and display it on 3 different stacked rows using CSS only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, handlebars.js

I am working on my friend's website on cargocollective.com.
on the Admin panel, there is a place to insert project names, afterward, you can display them as the thumbnails titles.

**This is how it looks now**
(the text should be: 
**Bright Diamonds**, **3 hyphens**, **Branding, Web Design, Art Direction** - same as in the 2'nd photo).

and beneath, how it should look after modification:
[image]

I've got access to modify her CSS file and to insert HTML content. 
(Imho - The HTML part is a little bit sketchy to use and the documentation suffers from a lack of examples to explain the usage.)
and I made this script:

```
Cargo.Event.on("homepage_loaded", function() {
   let titles = document.querySelectorAll("div.title");
   let titleArr;
   titles.forEach(el => {
      titleArr = el.innerText.split("|");
      el.innerHTML = `${titleArr[0]}<br>${titleArr[1]}<br>${titleArr[2]}`;
   });
});

Cargo.Event.trigger("homepage_loaded");
```

When I added:

```
titles[0].innerText = "Bright Diamonds|---|Branding, Web Design, Art Direction";
```

It worked in my browser but when I tried it over the system, the script refused to run.

My question is if the is another way to create the title as needed.

I added the: `.thumbnails .title` provided by cargo:

```
.thumbnails .title {
    margin-top: 1.2rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.1rem;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    font-family: 'Neue Haas Grotesk', Icons /*!Persona*/;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use html entity &#13;&#10; where you want line feed, or alternatively, create a :before/:after element, set content attribute including "\A" and set white-space to "pre" in css

Comment: Hi, @ibrahimtanyalcin, thanks for your quick answer.
The **&#13;&#10;** didn't work in my case.
Probably because cargocollective doesn't want to allow change of the layout using inserted HTML tags from the textField.
Here is how the text field looks:
**https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/938837/Screen%20Shot%202020-01-26%20at%2016.37.49.png**

My question is if there is any way to select specific words from the input text field 
and display them in different lines, the same as in the second photo I displayed in the image I added to my question.

Comment: I gave you 2 ways, try the second one, if that doesnt work for you, use plain spans or table. This looks like an A B C problem, a jsfiddle could really help.

Comment: I'm sure both of the solutions should work fine.

However:

For the 1'st solution: I guess cargocollective.com filters their textField, so any &313; or &#10; won't work.
For the 2'nd one: I can't modify the given template since the website is not mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case (*only cosmetic*) was in my CSS file:

(it is not mandatory to customize the width, but in case you want to, do it with:
**display: inline-block** as described below):

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
display: inline-block;
width: 40%;
```